# Pull data attributes from select menu instead of unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Ok, I have this custom google map that loads poins of interest from category links (on the right blue area)

http://livek2la.com/dev/neighborhood.html
I'm trying to convert this unordered list into an option select menu.

This an example of a category link that loads the data into the item list (gray area)

```
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-load="0" id="g0">Restaurants</a></li>
```

I can't find a way to convert these links into a select box
This is what I'm testing:

```
<select id="mixed" class="categorias">
<option data-id="0" data-load="g0">Restaurants</option>
<option data-id="1" data-load="g1">Spas</option>
<option data-id="2" data-load="g2">Entertainment</option>
</select>

<script>
$('#mixed').change(function() {$(this).find('option:selected').data('id').data('load');                         
});
</script>
```

http://livek2la.com/dev/neighborhood-test.html

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.
Mauricio